# BLENDER RIGIFY ERROR (Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "ear.L.004" not found')

Tags: rigging, bones, error, parent, rigify

I'm trying to rig a character for a project of mine. I've never rigged in Blender before, only 3DSMax. I'm using rigify Add>Armature>Human (Meta-Rig) and all I've done is replace the bones to different locations and tried to generate a rig. I've gotten a few errors I've tackled so far, but currently an error I have no been able to hurdle tells me this when I try to generate "Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "ear.L.004" not found'"

I have moved the ears outside of the head because the head of this model is a bird with a mullet. I do not need ear bones but have found that rigify humans do not generate rigs if all of the facial bones are not present as they were spawned. I plan to delete them once the rig is created.

So all that said, why is my rig not generating? And what do I need to change to make it function?

Here are my pictures of the model/problem:
http://prntscr.com/ueg8m3
http://prntscr.com/ueg8wx
http://prntscr.com/ueg9mh

I'd upload the .blend if I knew how. Please help, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Also, "ea.L.004" definitely exists http://prntscr.com/ueixra

Comment: If the bone is not deleted, then that's strange. Upload your metarig (without the character is fine) to https://pasteall.org/blend/ if you want someone to take a look.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/eed7f225aea247ff80f99b01573e761f I'd love for someone to

Answer (score 1):

I saw your file. The ear bone is there but it was not un-parented from the other bones for some reason
You have to parent

- ear.L.004 to ear.L.003
- ear.R.004 to ear.R.003

Parent with **Connected**.

Also your metarig has Scale that has not been applied so most likely you'll have to press CTRL+A > Scale (in Object Mode!)
[image]