# Rig generation error

Tags: rigging

[image]

When I try to make a rig for a skeleton model, I get this error.
How to fix it ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159556/generate-rig-error-key-org-nose-not-found https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194015/blender-rigify-error-generation-has-thrown-an-exception-bpy-prop-collectionk

Comment: Not one of the articles did not help.
And i add blend. file in description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigify face samples are intended to be used "as they are", without the ability of deleting bones: if you solve the error in the screenshot you will find that many others errors will come up, as many as the deleted bones: best way to fix is to create a new metarig, use the "snap to vertex" function to easily snap the new bones to your previous metarig (change the old metarig viewport display from octahedral to stick, to avoid confusion).

Don't delete any bone from the face: when the rig is generated enable the DEF bones layer (third from the last) and uncheck the "Deform" option from all the bones you don't want to use.

You can also hide all the unwanted controls and DEF bones in a hidden bone layer (in pose or edit mode press M to move the selected bones to a new layer).